# AWS ELB: Trailing slash issue :: Website is not loading

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, load-balancing, amazon-elb

**Scenario:**

- My website resolves to Aws ELB with 443 listener
- Backend Target group is an EC2 instance with apache running on port 8080

**Problem:**

- If I miss the trailing slash, the website does not resolve and when i put the trailing slash (/) everything works fine.
- [www.example.com/foldername](http://www.example.com/foldername) <-- Does not work, returns url [www.example.com:8080/foldername/](http://www.example.com:8080/foldername/) and resolution fails
- [www.example.com/foldername/](http://www.example.com/foldername/) <-- Does Works fine

To check if everything fine on the backend I queried the EC2 instance IP on port 8080 with and without /

- http://ec2_ip:8080/foldername and http://ec2_ip:8080/foldername/
- both url with instance ip worked as expected

I'm guessing something fails between ELB and EC2 instance

Vhost Config:

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost   *:8080>
         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
         Alias "/robots.txt" "/var/www/html/robots.txt"
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rootfolder
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
         <Directory /var/www/html/rootfolder>
           Options -Indexes
         </Directory>
       RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/script/(.*).js$ [NC]
        RewriteRule .* /script/some.php?file=%1.js [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} ^/js/subscribe\?hash=(.*)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /script-v2/some.php?file=sub&hash=%1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} ^/js/worker\?hash=(.*)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /script-v2/some.php?file=sw&hash=%1 [L]

 </VirtualHost>
```

Has anyone faced similar issue before?